# php artisan make:auth Terminal command gives empty response

Tags: laravel, terminal

Executing `php artisan make:auth` after `php artisan serve` returns nothing. The terminal just shows the cursor. I can type, but not execute any command.

Comment: Did you disable your antivirus before running the command? Antivirus may delete some of your laravel files.

Comment: I don't have any antivirus running.

Comment: Check your laravel root file and look for server.php and see if it's still exist.

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez Just checked and this file does exist in the root.

Comment: Okay, you need to add the server.php file there and you can get in github repo https://github.com/laravel/laravel based on your laravel version.

Comment: I think you misread my comment, the server.php file is there.

Comment: Ohps, okay. What Laravel version do you used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190267/discussion-between-bart-and-jesus-erwin-suarez).

Comment: Its sounds like you're running this incorrectly.. shouldn't you open a new terminal ? 
After executing php artisan serve, you're essentially starting a service the runs continuously until you exit it. so you'll need a second terminal in which you would perform your make:auth command... unless I'm missing the point here?

Comment: @ThatCoderGuy I think you're right, that's the answer!

Comment: glad I could help :)

Comment: @ThatCoderGuy Feel free to copy your response as an answer so I can approve/upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need need to open a new terminal.

After executing `php artisan serve`, you're essentially starting a service the runs continuously until you exit it. so you'll need a second terminal in which you would perform your `php artisan make:auth` command.